# Python Selenium find element XPath doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium

I try to find refresing elements (time minute) on the webpage. My code worked only for simple text earlier. Now I use *Ctrl+Shift+I* and point out my element and *"Copy Xpath"*.

Also, I have Chrome extension *"XPath helper"* and tried to do that with it one. There is more longer XPath, than in my code below. And it doesn't work too.

> Error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id....

And, I also tried to use find by class, by tag, by *CSS* selector.. It only worked by tag and no perfect, on different page.

And I don't even say about print it, sometimes `find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[...).text` work, sometimes not.

I don't understand, why it work on one page and not on second.. I want to work with find elements by *XPath* in flash later.

**UPDATE** Now I retrying code and it work! But still doesn't work on the next webpage.. why it is so changeable? XPath change, when page reload or what? What is the simplest way to get text(refresing) info from flash, opened in chrome browser?

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\vishniakov\Desktop\python bj\driver\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.betfair.com/sport/football/event?eventId=28935432")
print(driver.title)
elem =driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="yui_3_5_0_1_1538670363144_2571"]').text
print(elem)
```

Comment: the page is not immediately fully loaded: try to put a `sleep` of a couple of seconds before looking for the element: if that works, you may start to think at a better workaround

Comment: dynamic elements (not loaded immediately), hidden elements, elements which change are all reasons why something you "see" in a browser debugger or extension may fail via selenium. You may need to sleep, or use an ActionChain to make the item visible.

Comment: which element text you want as id's are dynamically generated so you will not get result

Answer (score 0):

This will work with **assumption you want data of that page not of any specific element**:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.betfair.com/sport/football/event?eventId=28935730")
print(driver.title)
elem =driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.scroller.context-event').text
print(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want spcipic data, you can use the `contains()` Xpath method... You can read about this [here](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html)

For your case:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\vishniakov\Desktop\python bj\driver\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.betfair.com/sport/football/event?eventId=28935432")
print(driver.title)
elements =driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@id, "yui_3_5_0_1_")]')
print([i.text for i in elements])
```

You can play around with the `contains()` if my example didn't work... You must find what part of the `id` changes and exclude that part of the ID.

Hope this helps you!